# I prefer individual lessons(,) where your teacher and you can be more concentrated/focused and work on specific topics

Tags: idiomatic-language, punctuation, relative-clauses, commas

1. Which word fits this sentence better?

> I prefer individual lessons(,) where your teacher and you can be more
> **concentrated/focused** and work on specific topics.

Cambridge Dictionary suggests that 'concentrated' might mean 'using a lot of effort to succeed at one particular thing':

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/concentrated

However, it somehow sounds as if I'm talking about juice. :) Can people be 'concentrated'?

2. Is the comma necessary in the sentence? I think it's a non-restrictive relative clause cause the information it introduces is not essential. Am I right?

Comment: I think "focused" is better, and that you do not need the comma.

Comment: **concentrated** is wrong here.  Yes, the *effort* can be concentrated, but the *student* is **concentrating**.

Comment: @EthanBolker thank you for your answer. Is there any explanation why the comma shouldn't be there?

Comment: @stangdon thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I prefer individual lessons(,) where your teacher and you can be more concentrated/focused and work on specific topics.

The term *focused* is more appropriate.  Also, as the relative clause is non-essential, comma is used.

I suggest changing the relative pronoun *where* to *during which* as the direct object, *individual lessons*, is *more* a time duration than a place.

> I prefer individual lessons, [*during which*] your teacher and you can be more *focused* and work on specific topics.

Guide on the use of the form *which + prepositions* is shown below.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-pronouns

> We can use which as the complement of a preposition:

> Close by, in the churchyard, is the famous Rudston stone, from which the village takes its name. (which refers to the famous Rudston stone and is the complement of from).

Comment: Thank you, Seowjooheng!